# Can we decrease the vertical height for each question in a list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I log into Workplace Stack Exchange, I see the following (before scrolling down):

[image: Workplace SE showing 2.5 questions]

As you can see, there are 2.5 questions visible thanks to a healthy amount of visual padding, making the total vertical height per question 120px. This is with 1280x800 resolution.

However on Stack Overflow, I see the following:

[image: Stack Overflow showing about 6 questions]

As you can see, there are nearly 6 questions visible without any need to scroll. Each question has a vertical height of 75px, which is almost 40% smaller than those on Workplace Stack Exchange.

I much prefer being able to see more questions without needing to scroll. Is it possible to reduce the vertical height of each question in the list? We may not need to reduce them all the way to 75px like Stack Overflow, but even a change to say 90px would mean more questions visible per page.

Is it possible to reduce the vertical height of each question in a list?

**Update March 22:** The [CSS updates](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/updates-to-the-site) from a few days ago help, but I still only see 3.25 questions when I would prefer to see 5 or 6:

[image]

Comment: This strikes me as a good idea

Comment: AFAIK, all SE sites do this when you click Questions and leave the default spoon-feed page. It's a horrible way to browse, six questions at a time; I don't use these buttons for this reason. This belongs on Meta.SE

Answer (score 2):

The [latest SE-wide CSS update](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/325) has fixed the spacing issue on the questions pages.  Yay!

I sure hope that was intentional. :-)

Our *header* is way bigger than theirs, but once you get down into the questions they look pretty close to me:

[image: Stack Overflow]

[image: Workplace]

Comment: I now see 3.25 questions instead of 2.5 questions. An improvement I guess, but I would prefer to see closer to 6 questions like on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Thunderforge part of that is our much-bigger header.  Once you get down into the questions our spacing is now much closer.  I added screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots. It doesn't look so bad on yours, but it seems you have a much taller monitor than me (mine is widescreen 1280 x 800). I've added an additional screenshot to the question showing what I see. Perhaps the issue then is that we ought to decrease the size of the header and/or the whitespace above the first question to accommodate those with shorter monitors (which would include netbooks and tablets not on the mobile site).

Comment: My monitor is 1280x1024, but I don't run full-screen or that would make the text too wide for me.  Yes the header is large (not just on this site  but on several others), but once I scroll a bit I can see a reasonable number of questions at once, so I just get used to doing that.  Yeah, the "every page needs a big header" meme that's sweeping the web is troublesome for those of us with smaller monitors, but at least for that there's something I can do, unlike the "add tons of whitespace between entries" problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you were noticing is Stack Overflow had a redesign recently while the other sites seem to have not caught up with the main site redesign. I’m only speaking for myself and what I’m seeing and what I've noticed. But I think that is the issue that's at play.

Someone with more details on the behind-the-scenes machinations of how these changes happen and evolve throughout the Stack Exchange sites could probably chime in and give better information.

Comment: There are other sites that have less vertical space than Workplace -- Mi Yodeya, ELU, UX (and they should know!), Seasoned Advice, Travel, all beta sites... it's not just that SO changed.

Answer (score -1):

While I agree that there could be some savings in WP.SE question height, I would say that it shouldn't be just as high.

The main reason is because SO and WP.SE are aimed at different audiences. SO is a purely developer-related SE site which has been around for a few years now. The target audience is tech-savvy IT-employees who are primarily looking for solutions to a problem. Due to the age and popularity of S0, a LOT of problems have already been answered, so users are encouraged to first look for existing answers before asking a question. Because of this, the question lists and overall layout are altered to show more questions on the same space.

WP.SE, on the other hand, is a site aimed at general employees looking for advice on problems they have with the workplace. This site doesn't yet have the userbase or snowball effect that SO has, so there's a good chance your question hasn't been asked (or answered) yet, or that similar issues are too different from yours. YOu are still encouraged to search first and ask questions afterwards, but due to the variations in workplaces, your question is likely to sufficiently different from existing ones.

In addition, your comparison image isn't quite accurate. It's not just the vertical height, but also the width AND the rest of the page. WP.SE has a lot more open room before the questions even start, with the questions starting about halfway down your image. The questions box is also narrower than on SO, because of the sidebar. This means that it's easier for questions to be long enough to not fit on 1 line, leading to less questions visible. The SO image is also 50 pixels higher, making the size comparison misleading in favor of SO.

In case of the frontpage, SO also has a larger focus on helping others. having more questions on the frontpage visible at once allows users to see more questions with their preferred tags without searching. WP.SE is more of a site that's visited on a daily basis, while SO is often visited on a hourly basis by programmers looking for answers.

Comment: While I agree that this site requires more searching, I'm not sure what that has to do with the number of questions seen on the main page (among other places), which is what is shown in the original question.

Comment: @Thunderforge I added clarification on how the front page design is additionally affected by the different userbase.