# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

My name is Stéphane and I'm the designer at Stack Exchange who [made the design of this site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2331/168). You may have noticed some updates to the design lately.

The updates are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework (the code which display the design).

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

If you see any bugs please let us know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!  And thanks again for the beautiful design of our site.

Comment: _"More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future"_ -- means, this update partially covers some [technical debt](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/132857/31260)? :)

Comment: Has the font changed? I remember it was a different font.

Comment: @LéoLam We went from "Open Sans" to the font stack "Helvetica Neue/Helvetica/Arial". It makes the site render faster because it doesn't load a custom font.

Comment: I see. Nice update; it still looks like Workplace.SE, unlike some other sites who seem to have “lost” their design and now resemble other sites.

Answer (score 3):

While I like the improvements, there is still one issue that I think should be addressed:

[Can we decrease the vertical height for each question in a list?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3075/8233)

This is a highly upvoted meta issue that has been open for over a month. The issue is that only 2-3 questions are visible on the main page "above the fold" whereas on Stack Overflow there are closer to 6 questions visible without any scrolling. Myself and all of the users who upvoted the issue would really appreciate you adjusting the CSS to accomodate this.

(Other ways to solve the issue might include decreasing the size of the header and/or the amount of white space between the header and the top of the first quesiton).

Comment: It's already done, we decreased a lot the vertical height of the question list, see http://cl.ly/image/3Z1H1D2V2b3b